# Surjection/Injection in Product of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I wish somebody could help me with this one.

Let $S: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^4$ and $T: \mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear transformation such that $T*S$ is the identity map of $R^3$. Then which of the following is correct?

$1) S*T$ is the identity map of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$2) S*T$ is one-one, but not onto.

$3) S*T$ is onto, but not one-one.

$4) S*T$ is neither one-one nor onto.

I am trying to solve it with an example.

Let $R^3$ has $2$ members- $abc,pqr$ and let $R^4$ also has $2$ members- $abcd,pqrs$. Say, $S(abc)=abcd$, also $S(abc)=pqrs$. So, $S$ is onto and one-one because range equals co-domain and every image has at most one pre-image. For $T*S$ to be identity, $T(abcd)=abc$ and $T(pqrs)=abc$. Here, $T$ is neither onto nor one-one because range is not equal to co-domain and an image has $2$ pre-images. Also, $S*T$ is not identity, if we consider a case where $T(abcd)=abc$ and $S(abc)=pqrs$. But how to check for the other parts of the question? Does behaviour of product of linear transformation (regarding onto/one-one) same as that of the first transformation?

Another related question, do we have a term for a function in which there is no image for a particular value of domain, like $S$ in this question?

Comment: "Say, S(abc)=abcd, also S(abc)=pqrs." But this can never happen! Functions don't work like this. If you plug in an input, you get *one* output.

Comment: Also, why not just pick an explicit example? The first example I think of is $$S = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, T = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ What properties does this have?

Comment: Consider the dimension of $\rm{image}(ST) = S(\rm{image}(T))$ in comparison to the dimension of $\rm{codom}(ST)=\rm{dom}(ST) = R^4$.

Comment: @Billy- I understood your input/output point. Thanks. Regarding, properties, I didn't get you. Maybe I should first revise matrix part.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis- Can you please elabotate your point. Are co-domain and image not same here? I think they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say $R^3$ I assume you mean $\mathbb{R}^3=\{(x, y, z):x, y, z\in\mathbb{R}\}$. So when you say "let $R^3$ have two members" this doesn't make sense, it is already defined. Let us go through each of your questions.

1.) Since domain of $S$ is 3-dimensional and range is 4 it cannot be onto. Thus $ST$ is not the identity.

2.) Since the domain of T is 4 dimensional and range is 3 it cannot be one-to-one. Thus $ST$ is not one-to-one.

3.) As I said above $ST$ is not onto.

4.) So from above we can see that $ST$ is neither one-to-one nor onto.

Note: Since your spaces are finite dimensional we can use the Rank-Nullity theorem and so since the domain and range of $ST$ is the same space, $ST$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

For your last question, this is impossible, by definition if a point, $x$, is in the domain of some function $S$, then $S(x)$ is some value in the range. That's what it means to be in the domain.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point? "Since domain of S is 3-dimensional and range is 4 it cannot be onto."

Comment: In general $dim (S(V))\leq dim(V)$. To see this take a spanning set for $V$ apply $S$ to it and note that it is a spanning set for $S(V)$.

Comment: Sure, $dim(S(V)) \le dim(V)$, but what does that have to do with onto? I wish you could explain.

Comment: Let $S:V\rightarrow W$, if $dim(V)<dim(W)$, then $dim(S(V))<dim(W)$. So $S(V)$ is a $\textit{proper}$ subspace of $W$, so it isn't all of $W$. Thus $S$ is not onto.

Comment: That's an interesting point. Thanks. So, $S$ is not onto. But how to tell about $S*T$? Like I've asked in OP, "Does behaviour of product of linear transformation (regarding onto/one-one) same as that of one of the transformation?" If yes, does that mean even $T*S$ is not onto?

Comment: It isn't always the same but if S is not onto then neither is ST.